# How to eliminate duplicate data from two select query in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two select queries, which returns below result sets.

ResultSet1:

```
FIELD_NAME      DISPLAY        MASK         DEFAULTVALUE
LOANTYPE        1           Test LoanType       2
PREAPPROVAL     1           Test Preapproval    2
```

ResultSet2:

```
 FIELDNAME       DISPLAY    MASK                DEFAULTVALUE
  LOANTYPE                  NA                  NA
  INTEREST                  NA                  NA
  HOMETYPE                  NA                  NA
  PREAPPROVAL               NA                  NA
  PURCHASERTYPE             NA                  NA
  PURPOSE                   NA                  NA
  PREAPPROVAL               NA                  NA
```

I want to get the result like below. Any help will be appreciated.

```
    FIELD_NAME      DISPLAY        MASK         DEFAULTVALUE
  LOANTYPE           1          Test LoanType       2
  PREAPPROVAL        1          Test Preapproval    2
  INTEREST                        NA                NA
  HOMETYPE                        NA                NA
  PREAPPROVAL                     NA                NA
  PURCHASERTYPE                   NA                NA
  PURPOSE                         NA                NA
  PREAPPROVAL                     NA                NA
```

Here LOANTYPE and PREAPPROVAL values need to be remove from duplication.I tried two CTE with right join.But it is not giving the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try by using window function row_number()

```
 with cte as
(
SELECT *,row_number() over(partition by FIELD_NAME order by DISPLAY desc,MASK desc,DEFAULTVALUE desc) rn
   FROM (
   Query1 
   UNION 
   Query2
     ) t
) select * from cte where rn=1
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use an outer join and `coalesce()`:

```
select r2.field_name,
       coalesce(r1.display, r2.display) as display,
       coalesce(r1.mask, r2.mask) as mask,
       coalesce(r1.defaultvalue, r2.defaultvalue) as defaultvalue
 from resultset2 r2 left join
      resultset1 r1
      on r1.field_name = r2.field_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below using left join and CASE WHEN

Instead of CASE WHEN you can use coalesce() function if your table2 values are null

```
select 
   a.FIELD_NAME, 
   case when a.DISPLAY='NA' then b.display else a.display end as DISPLAY,
   case when a.MASK='NA' then b.Mask else a.mask end as MASK,         
   case when a.DEFAULTVALUE='NA' then b.defaultvalue else a.defaultvalue end as Defaultvalue
 from resultset2 a left join resultset1 b 
 on a.loantype=b.loadtype
```